# "Get married SOMEWHERE" in this context

Tags: grammar, prepositions

As we can say:

> He got married **into** a prosperous family.

Can I say:

> He got married **in / to** London(spouse's city).

And:

> He got married **around / about** London.
>   {When the exact place is **unknown.}**

Please explain.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't say "He got married into a prosperous family".  It would have to be "He married into a prosperous family" (although this *might* just be a difference between American English and British English).

You can say "He got married **in** London." (because that is the place).  "He got married **to** London" would mean he married someone called "London".

"He got married around London." is just wrong.  You could say **near** if the marriage location was outside, but not far from London.  You could say **in or near** if you know it was not far from London and possibly in London.